# update label or textbox in masterpage header dynamically without postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, e-commerce

I have a cart / basket page, I would like to show a summary of no. of items and running total within the master page header, currently the values will appear in the master page but are not changing when the cart is modified until a full page refresh. 
is there a way to dynamically update the master without refresh ?

Comment: try to use an `Updatepanel`

Comment: What type to content are you showing in header. Is it simply a count of item added to basket?

Comment: yes, total items and total value, thanks.

Comment: how you are showing them? are you using label ?

Comment: Aren't Javascript or Jquery helping you out? From codebehind do an async call using `Scriptmanager` and update the label text using javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, there are numerous ways to do this, and all of the best ways would involve a client-side library of your choice.  jQuery, KnockoutJS, and AngularJS are all obvious examples to get this done.

You'll want to ensure that you have an event/listener built-in, or whatever the equivalent for the framework is that you choose to go with.  This way, you can have instant results when an add to cart action occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Master page is a handler of all your pages. Let's call it a template. You can throw your label or textbox TEXT content from cookies. What i mean is from normal page to Master Page.

You can hide the value from cookies and display it in any position you want in Master page.

Here's the flow:
On your Normal Page:
1. HttpCookie sumcookie = new HttpCookie("Sumcookie");
2. sumcookie["sumcookie "]=//The sum of your calculated number here. make it a string if you want "number.toString()";
3. Response.Cookies.Add(sumcookie);

On your Master Page:
1. HttpCookie getSumcookie = Request.Cookies["sumcookie"];
2. yourlabel.text = getSumcookie["sumcookie"];

Hope this could help.